# Mouse events are not working when including the Bootstrap 4 in the header

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm just playing around with Bootstrap 4 with Jquery. I have created one Navbar where there are 4 links in which 4th has the submenu. If I hover on that link it will open the submenu. But it only works if I don't provide bootstrap CDN. If I provide it, it stops working.

I tried downloading both bootstrap CSS and jquery min js. It didn't help. I can do this with custom CSS but I want to do it with the jQuery only.

---

Code

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dropDown-nav, #submenu").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("mouse entered");
    $("#submenu").show();
  });

  $("#submenu, #dropDown-nav").mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("mouse left");
    $("#submenu").hide();
  });

  $(".topnav a").click(function(event) {
    $("a").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(".dropbtn").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $("a").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".dropbtn").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(this).css('color', '#2F3942');
  });

  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function(event) {
    $(".topnav a").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(".dropbtn").css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".topnav a").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".dropbtn").css('color', '#2F3942');
    $(this).css('color', '#2F3942');
  });

});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
#mainNav {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainNav_2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#mainNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0D5DB8;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 6em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2F3942;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forMargin {
  margin-right: 15px;
}


/* 
    .topnav a:active{
        background-color: #E1E1E1;
        color: #2F3942; 
    } */


/* .active {
      background-color: #E1E1E1;
      color: #2F3942;
    } */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2F3942;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: E1E1E1;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2F3942;
  color: E1E1E1;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    } */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-sm j" id="mainNav">
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_3">
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#A" class="forMargin">A</a>
  <a href="#B" class="forMargin">B</a>
  <a href="#C" class="forMargin">B</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropDown-nav" class="forMargin">D 
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="submenu">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<!-- <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
                    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
            </div> -->
```

I want to see hover working with Bootstrap and jQuery.

Comment: it seems to be calling the listeners... what is not working is the show/hide, but the mouse events are being called

Comment: That's true. I can see the log statements but show/hide is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to increase `.dropdown-content`'s `z-index` (or remove it) and also remove that `position: absolute`.

Check below snippet, is that what you need?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dropDown-nav, #submenu").mouseenter(function() {
    console.clear()
    console.log("mouse entered");
    $("#submenu").show();
  });

  $("#submenu, #dropDown-nav").mouseleave(function() {
    console.clear()
    console.log("mouse left");
    $("#submenu").hide();
  });

  $(".topnav a").click(function(event) {
    $("a").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(".dropbtn").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $("a").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".dropbtn").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(this).css('color', '#2F3942');
  });

  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function(event) {
    $(".topnav a").css('background-color', '#2F3942');
    $(".dropbtn").css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".topnav a").css('color', '#E1E1E1');
    $(".dropbtn").css('color', '#2F3942');
    $(this).css('color', '#2F3942');
  });

});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
#mainNav {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainNav_2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#mainNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0D5DB8;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 6em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2F3942;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.forMargin {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #2F3942;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: E1E1E1;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2F3942;
  color: E1E1E1;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    } */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-sm j" id="mainNav">
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="mainNav_3">
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#A" class="forMargin">A</a>
  <a href="#B" class="forMargin">B</a>
  <a href="#C" class="forMargin">B</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropDown-nav" class="forMargin">D 
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="submenu">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the same thing as I can see by running your code. But I tried on my PC and also on jsfiddle but the same thing is not working :(

Comment: well, if all the code and scripts you have is in your question, then I really don't know how to help, when you inspect `.dropdown-content` with devTools, which css/styles you can see?

Comment: I can see the same css as in the css file. 

    display: none;
    background-color: #2F3942;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 10;

Comment: have you tried increase z-index or even remove it?
I really don't know how to help if the code works here but not works on your computer

Comment: In both the case didn't get the dropdown :(

Comment: Yeah I'm 100% sure about it. Check this :  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Dorb9TOmrl

Comment: Can you see the code working in the above jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't see it working. Don't know what's the problem.

Comment: I tried to do it again on https://jsfiddle.net/j30pe2Ln/. I can't see it working. Do you?

Comment: Oh It's working now. Then there is something wrong in my laptop.

Comment: It is working now but I appreciate if you have any idea about why it is not working in my Laptop.

Comment: Can you help me with one thing? If you had seen if I hover on the navbar it opens the submenu and submenu width is full I believe. I just want the width as the submenu item width only. How to achieve that?

Comment: comments are not for extending conversation, if now you have another question, please, create a new one here in SO (then mark me there), or see if you don't find an answer among many questions here in SO